# String cannot be cast to class UserDetailsImpl

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I already tried to find something related to this but all questions are different and I caught myself staring at the screen for the past three hours without success to solve this.

So previously I had a login and registration on same page, and back then login controller worked fine. I had to do some refactoring and needed to separate login and registration form on two HTML pages and now login form doesn't work. So now when I insert username and password and click on login I get `There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).` and this error in stack trace

Error is:

```
 class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class com.budgettracker.demo.security.token.services.UserDetailsImpl (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.budgettracker.demo.security.token.services.UserDetailsImpl is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

This is UserDetailsImpl which is mentioned in error:

```
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long id;

private String username;

private String email;

private String firstName;

@JsonIgnore
private String password;

private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

public UserDetailsImpl(Long id, String username, String email, String firstName, String password,
                       Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.password = password;
    this.authorities = authorities;
}

public static UserDetailsImpl build(User user) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream()
            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().name()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new UserDetailsImpl(
            user.getId(),
            user.getUsername(),
            user.getEmail(),
            user.getFirstName(),
            user.getPassword(),
            authorities);
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
}


@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;
    UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) o;
    return Objects.equals(id, user.id);
}
```

}

Any suggestion what can be the problem? Do I need to provide something more, maybe something else is also related to this error? I'm here just ask.

**EDIT 1**

I also found that maybe this can cause problem, this is inside my `UserDetailsServiceImpl`

```
  @Override
  @Transactional
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found with username: " + username));

    return UserDetailsImpl.build(user);
  }
```

This is `login controller`:

```
 @PostMapping("/login")
@Transactional
public String login(@ModelAttribute("login") @Valid LoginRequest loginRequest, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

    ResponseCookie jwtCookie = jwtUtils.generateJwtCookie(user);

    boolean thereAreErrors = result.hasErrors();
    if (thereAreErrors) {
        model.addAttribute("login", loginRequest);
        return "login";
    }

    model.addAttribute("login", loginRequest);

    ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, jwtCookie.toString());

    return "redirect:/api/test/homePage";

}
```

`Thymeleaf form:`

```
 <form
            method="post"
            role="form"
            th:action="@{/api/auth/login}"
            th:object="${login}">

        <label for="chk" aria-hidden="true">Login</label>

        <input
                class="form-control"
                id="usernameLogin"
                name="username"
                placeholder="Enter username"
                th:field="*{username}"
                type="text"
                required/>

        <p th:errors="*{username}" class="text-danger"
           th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}"></p>

        <input
                class="form-control"
                id="passwordLogin"
                name="password"
                placeholder="Enter password"
                th:field="*{password}"
                type="password"
                required/>

        <p th:errors="*{password}" class="text-danger"
           th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}"></p>

        <button>Login</button>
    </form>
```

`Full stack trace:`

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class com.budgettracker.demo.security.models.User (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.budgettracker.demo.security.models.User is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at com.budgettracker.demo.security.controllers.TestController.index(TestController.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
at com.budgettracker.demo.security.controllers.TestController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$de5ce390.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.invokeMethod(CglibAopProxy.java:386) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.access$000(CglibAopProxy.java:85) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:704) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at com.budgettracker.demo.security.controllers.TestController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6e3ec78e.index(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at com.budgettracker.demo.security.token.jwt.AuthTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthTokenFilter.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

`Index` controller:

```
@GetMapping("/homePage")
public String index(Model model, Principal principal) {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    long userId = user.getId();
    model.addAttribute("userId", userId);

    return "homepage";
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in here that will throw the exception. I suspect it is coming from submitting to the wrong URL.

Comment: Thanks for helping! Here is the `form th:action` >> `th:action="@{/api/auth/login}"` and this is in controller, on top of the class I have `@RequestMapping("/api/auth")`  and then on top of the controller `@PostMapping("/login")`. Its also weird for me, and as you said maybe its wrong URL since I didnt change a single line in config for security, just added pages as I said. But I cant find out where problem can be actually

Comment: The URL doesn't tell me a thing... It is the controller... Also post the **full stacktrace** (why do people always post a non-telling snippet of stacktrace) as that contains valuable information.

Comment: Question is updated with the controller and full stacktrace. Also I have added Thymeleaf form

Comment: If you check the stacktrace (which you apparently didn't) you clearly see the error is coming from the `TestController.index` method and not even your `login` method. So I suspect everything is working but your redirect after login is borked.

Comment: Question is updated with Index controller , yeah, my bad. What can be then? Code doesnt take a user id well? When I run debugger, principal field is null

Comment: Well what is line 47, that is your culprit line.

Comment: Yes, it is `long userId = user.getId();` Actually, my bad, its `UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();` and when I click on error cursor points at `(UserDetailsImpl)`

Comment: So `getPrincipal` returns a `String` (the username) not a full `UserDetailsImpl`.

Comment: What can I try in order to try to solve this? Here is the repo, branch is feature/valid-inputs if you have a time and want to help https://github.com/sjankdev/budgettracker-final/tree/feature/validate-inputs

Comment: Btw. principal is null just empty when I press login with debugger

Comment: I'm not talking about `Principal` the `authentication.getPrincipal` the line you pointed as is returning a `String`.

Comment: I'm totally losted right now :D Never mind, will continue trying later

Comment: Anyway, I tried something and managed to get on home page, I set ID as path variable on URL and than pass ID on redirect `@GetMapping("/homePage/{id}")
    public String homePage(@PathVariable(value = "id") long userId, Model model) {` but I have problem now, when I want to access another page Its says bad credentials